# How to hide child div without having ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, I need to hide all divs inside parent div except the first one.
Problem is, divs have no ID or anything.

Is there a possible way how to do it? Preferably by CSS or pure JS?

```
<div role="list" class="slds-form">
    <div class="slds-grid">Visible</div>
    <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
    <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: Might this be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: `.slds-form > div:not(:first-child){ display:none;  }` try this one.

Comment: Learn here about child in css using `nth-child`:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-child`:

```css
.slds-form > div:nth-child(n + 2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="slds-form">
  <div class="slds-grid">Visible</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***This will work for you:***

> you can combine child selection(`:first-child`) with `:not` to attain
>   the result you want.

```css
.slds-form > div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="slds-form">
  <div class="slds-grid">Visible</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
</div>
```

*Hope this was helpfull for you.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not(:first-child)`:

```css
.slds-form>div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="slds-form">
  <div class="slds-grid">Visible</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
  <div class="slds-grid">Hide</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can add an extra class to toggle show hide.

```
.slds-hide {
  display: none;
}
.slds-show {
  display: block;
}

<div role="list" class="slds-form">
  <div class="slds-grid slds-show">Visible</div>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-hide">Hide</div>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-hide">Hide</div>
</div>
```